# .NET CORE: Dapper map many-to-many query

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-core, mapping, dapper

I'm trying to learn Dapper and I'm stuck trying to map a query on a many-to-many relation. In this case I have three models and respective tables, CourseModel, StudentCourseModel and StudentViewModel.

I'm trying to create a detail view where you can display a student with all the courses he or she is attending. This is how I'm trying to access the data, but for some reason only one record of 'course' is set in the student course-list even though a student is attending more than on course. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

**CourseModel**

```
    public class CourseModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CourseCode { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string CourseDescription{ get; set; }

    }
```

**StudentCourseModel**

```
    public class StudentCourseModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public int CourseId { get; set; }
    }
```

**StudentViewModel**

```
    public class StudentViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public List<CourseModel> Courses { get; set; }

        public StudentViewModel()
        {
            Courses = new List<CourseModel>();
        }
    }
```

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int id)
        {
            using (IDbConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=SchoolSystemDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"))
            {
                var p = new
                {
                    Id = id
                };

                string sql = $@"select dbo.Students.*, dbo.Courses.*
                            from dbo.Students
                            INNER JOIN[dbo].[StudentCourses] ON dbo.StudentCourses.StudentID = dbo.Students.Id
                            INNER JOIN[dbo].[Courses] ON dbo.Courses.Id = dbo.StudentCourses.CourseId
                            WHERE dbo.Students.Id = @Id";

                StudentViewModel student = cnn.Query<StudentViewModel, CourseModel, StudentViewModel>(sql,
                    (StudentViewModel, CourseModel) =>
                    {
                        StudentViewModel.Courses.Add(CourseModel);
                        return StudentViewModel;
                    },
                    p).First();

                return View(student);

            }
        }
```

Comment: Set a break-point inside StudentViewModel constructor. My guess is that it is called for every instance of CourseModel. See https://dapper-tutorial.net/query

Answer (score 0):

I also struggled with many-to-many mappings as I learned to use dapper.

For me the following procedure proved helpful:

When building a mapping function, you execute the query once in a database modelling tool such as *SSMS* to see how the structure of the queried data is.

You then imagine that for every returned line in the query result the mapping function is executed. You therefore need to keep track of the data that was already processed by the mapping function. The StudentViewModel instance passed into the function represents the one of the current row, which explains why you only have one Course attached.

To keep track of the students, you can use a lookup-dictionary outside of your mapping function. (couldn't test the sample below atm)

```cs
    var studentLookup = new Dictionary<int, StudentViewModel>();
    
    var res = cnn
        .Query<StudentViewModel, CourseModel, StudentViewModel>(
           sql,
           (svm, cm) =>
           {
               // Check if the student was already processed; if so, retrieve the reference
               if (!studentLookup.TryGetValue(svm.Id, out var student))
               {
                   student = svm;
                   studentLookup.Add(svm.Id, student);
               }
    
               // add course to the student that is assigned with the current record
               if (svm.Courses == null)
               {
                   svm.Courses = new List<CourseModel>();
               }
                            
               if (svm.Courses.All(x => x.Id != cm.Id))
               {
                   svm.Courses.Add(cm);
               }
                            
               return svm;
           },
           new { Id = id });
```